# Fix ASP.NET Core deprecated package

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, upgrade, nuget-package, deprecated

I have a Mend Bolt warning because of this old version for encodings.web: `system.text.encodings.web.4.5.0.nupkg`. Version 4.5.0 has security vulnerabilities. I need to upgrade to a higher version.

It is added as a transitive package from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions`:

[image: transitive package]

The problem is version 2.2.0 for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions` is deprecated.

My project uses .NET 6. I cannot find that package in a newer format or another variant. I use `Hosting.Abstractions` for `IWebHost` class, for a migration extension method. If I uninstall it, then the warning is solved but my method does not build.

```
public static IWebHost MigrateDbContext<TContext>(this IWebHost webHost, Action<TContext, IServiceProvider> seeder) where TContext : DbContext
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<TContext>>();
    var context = services.GetService<TContext>();
    ...
    context.Database.Migrate();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Since you're on .NET 6, can you just remove the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions package? Things have changed since .NET Core 2.x, and now ASP.NET Core has a "framework reference", and no longer need package references for APIs that are "in box"

Comment: Regarding both questions, I do not find class `IWebHost` if I install first proposed package or if I remove the AspNetCore variant. I use `.NET 6.0`, but it does not seem to have that already in box.
https://imgur.com/xSG3X4D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed latest stable version for that vulnerable package. In future, after I upgrade to another .NET version and maybe that vulnerability goes away, I will need to go back and remove that line from `.csproj` where `System.Text.Encodings.Web` is set to today's latest version.

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web" Version="6.0.0" />
```

Also, I needed to check every project to see where my vulnerable package is. Fortunately, my project is small, and I could do that. For bigger applications we will need a library to find transitive packages.

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about System.Drawing.Common though.

Comment: Sorry, I had problems with both packages in the same manner and while writing the solution I used the second package that remained behind. Edited the answer.